# Too many Linux sites

Tags: discussion, scope

I see that Stack Overflow is very Linux specific. Doesn't *Unix & Linux* and *Ask Ubuntu* cover much of the same ground? I see that *Unix & Linux* and Server Fault also cater to many Linux server questions. Similarly, *Ask Ubuntu* and Super User seems to contain most like questions.

Comment: Stack Overflow, Server Fault and Super User are _not_ Linux specific, what makes you think they are?

Comment: Anyway, I got his point that a question related to Linux may fit into more than one of those sites. And there is also a fact that there are people who can't distinguish between Linux, Ubuntu and UNIX - including myself - don't know which site fits the question better and choose any of them.

Comment: @nhahtdh If you don't know the difference between Linux/Unix and Ubuntu, it's rather unlikely that you need to ask a question that would need to go to either of those sites.

Comment: @Juhana: For example, a newbie, working in a *nix like environment, but he doesn't know the actual OS, and doesn't even care to look up what OS it is. He just know enough UNIX commands to not be uncomfortable to navigate around. People like that may have question about how to some task that they are not aware of. And there is the fact that a lot of the same tools are available on different distros.

Comment: @nhahtdh Is that an actual problem or a hypothetical one? I can't imagine anyone going "I'm using Unix, but I don't know which flavor. I wonder if I should post this question to the Unix site?"

Comment: @Juhana: I am using my own case as an example. One of my school's server is Sun Fire, and I keep hearing UNIX workshop, and we have another cluster with some other *nix like OS - I am confused by all those that I currently do "feature-detection" rather than caring about actual OS I am working on. It is currently sufficient to do that since I am not touching admin stuffs, which are more likely to differ between the flavors.

Comment: This shows microsoft is a noob :p

Comment: **[Unix and Ubuntu: Why Both?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/unix-and-ubuntu-why-both/)**

Comment: @RobertCartaino Thanks for pointing me to this wonderful article.

Answer (score 6):

Context would be useful here.

SE occasionally partners with other organisations - AU is pretty much the *official* Ubuntu Q&A site (I'm uncertain if there's a full official partnership). With SU and SF, Linux falls under a broader scope that the sites support - SF is for professional sysadmins, and Linux, BSD and Windows *all* get used inside large organisations. With SU the scope is for personal use hardware and software. Both SF and SU predate *Unix & Linux*.

On the other hand, the SE network has many sites with specific topics such as religion (for example, Judaism and Christianity), hobbies (biking and gaming) and so on. Unix and Linux is merely a subset of computers that happens to benefit from its own site.

If you believe that SE has a Linux bias, I'd point out this site runs on a Windows/IIS/SQL Server/.NET backend.

If it's a matter of too much choice, you obviously need to get to know the site cultures. SF is great if you have a properly difficult question, in a professional environment (but try not to ask anything too basic, or outside a professional setting). On SU, quite a bit goes, and it's fairly easy going, and it's a good place to ask personal use questions. AU does Ubuntu, and nothing else. I'm unfamiliar with UL.

The two specialist sites are relatively unusual, and SU and SF are broad enough for any OS to be supported in their respective context. There's no real Linux bias at all.